# how to display a value other than the renderValue in material ui select

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have a dropwdown that has to display the flags of 3 countries and I have to choose one. 
But the dropdown logic works differently depending on the renderValue.
I have 3 different cases :

**Case 1**

```
renderValue={value => <img src={value.country[0]} alt="RenderValue" />}
```

the flag of the renderValue is displayed but if you try to choose another value you have an error:

```
The above error occurred in the <ForwardRef(SelectInput)> component: (...)
Consider adding an error boundary to your tree to customize error handling behavior.
```

---

**Case 2**

```
renderValue={value => <img src={value[0]} alt="RenderValue" />}
```

the flag of the renderValue does not appear and if you try to choose another value it keeps displaying the RenderValue

---

**Case 3**

```
The renderValue is removed
```

Everything works but we have more rendervalue

---

Here is the select : https://codesandbox.io/s/reverent-fermat-zssow?fontsize=14

you can play with all three cases. Case 3 is the default case :)

I want the select to work with a renderValue I don't know what I'm doing wrong

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is unclear to me what you were trying to achieve with the `renderValue` function. This is only useful if you want the selected value to look different than the corresponding `MenuItem`, but the content you had in the `renderValue` appeared to have the same intent as the `MenuItem` (show the flag image).

The main thing I changed to get things showing properly is to leverage the imported flag images when constructing the countries array and I fixed the initialization of the `country` state to be one of the valid values (rather than an object with an array of all the values).

If you still think you need to use `renderValue`, please clarify what you want to be rendered differently about the selected value vs. how it displays when the `Select` is open.

Here's my modified version of your sandbox:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import InputLabel from "@material-ui/core/InputLabel";
import MenuItem from "@material-ui/core/MenuItem";
import FormControl from "@material-ui/core/FormControl";
import Select from "@material-ui/core/Select";
import France from "./assets/flags/france.png";
import Allemagne from "./assets/flags/germany.png";
import Suisse from "./assets/flags/switzerland.png";

const countries = [
  {
    label: "France",
    src: France,
    link: " ",
    value: "FR"
  },
  {
    label: "Allemagne",
    src: Allemagne,
    link: " ",
    value: "DE"
  },
  {
    label: "Suisse",
    src: Suisse,
    link: " ",
    value: "CH"
  }
];

const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  button: {
    display: "block",
    marginTop: theme.spacing(2)
  },
  formControl: {
    margin: theme.spacing(5),
    minWidth: 120,
    backgroundColor: "transparent"
  },
  select: {
    textAlign: "center",
    textDecoration: "none"
  }
}));
function App() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const [country, setCountry] = React.useState(France);
  const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(false);

  const handleChange = event => {
    setCountry(event.target.value);
  };

  const handleClose = () => {
    setOpen(false);
  };

  const handleOpen = () => {
    setOpen(true);
  };

  return (
    <form autoComplete="off">
      <FormControl className={classes.formControl}>
        <InputLabel htmlFor="open-select" />
        <Select
          open={open}
          onClose={handleClose}
          onOpen={handleOpen}
          value={country}
          name="country"
          onChange={handleChange}
          inputProps={{
            id: "open-select"
          }}
        >
          {countries.map((option, key) => (
            <MenuItem value={option.src} key={key}>
              <img src={option.src} alt={option.label} />{" "}
            </MenuItem>
          ))}
        </Select>
      </FormControl>
    </form>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

[image: Edit Country/Flag Select]

Comment: I don't need the renderValue anymore since you declare the default value here  : const [country, setCountry] = React.useState(France); thks a lot